# Power BI Count time values

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm working in Power BI. I've got some pallets registerd on specific times during a day. I want a chart that shows the registerd times of the day with a goal line of 2 hours 02:00:00.. Any Idea how to show this chart?
[image]
Thanks!

BR

Comment: Please explain better how end result should look like, best is image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, not sure if you also have a date table which would make this a lot easier to visualize but given the fields you have provided, I was able to come up with this solution:

Convert your time stamp by creating a calculated column representing true time (I couldn't figure out how to change formatting to display time correctly) so I just added 12 hours to your values:

```
True Time :=
Table[Time] + TIME ( 12, 0, 0 )
```

Then take the difference between your 'Goal Line' and the Time Stamp and insert those values into a calculated column:

```
Goal Line and TimeStamp Delta :=
DATEDIFF ( TIME ( 14, 0, 0 ), Sheet1[True Time], MINUTE )
```

Now you using an area chart with you 'Barcode' as your "Axis" and the [Goal Line and TimeStamp Delta] measure as your "Values" you can create a visual that will show all bar codes that have been processed before 2 pm as negative and everything passed 2 pm as positive.

[image]